# Android Studio is not recognizing Kotlin classes in the middle of Java classes

Tags: java, android, kotlin

The class called Google Mapas (which is a class in Kotlin in the middle of the Java classes) is created, programmed without errors, and declared in Android Manifest without errors.
Google Mapas means Google Maps in Portuguese language.
However Android Studio does not recognize the Google Mapas class.

File in attachment:
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/PTro5Gk

Please, what to do?
[image]

Comment: Please do not upload images of code: paste the code into your question.

Comment: Adding the complete stacktrace may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way is

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GoogleMaps::class.java))
```

try one this and feedback the result.

Comment: You’re mixing Kotlin and Java syntax. The OP’s code is in a Java file and is correct Java syntax.

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work.